# Smartfoxserver2x + spring + hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, smartfoxserver

I want to create a project using **smartfoxserver2x** with spring framework and hibernate.

But I can't find how to use spring and hibernate in smartfoxserver2x.

Could someone help me?

I had put these code in the init method that I found on other website,but it still didn't work.

this is the code.

```
ClassLoader origLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    ClassLoader extensionLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(extensionLoader);

    context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(new ClassPathResource("/applicationContext.xml", extensionLoader));

    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(origLoader);
```

and this is the exception

> 15:28:15,741 ERROR [main] managers.SFSExtensionManager     - java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>   Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Message: *** Null ***
>   Description: Extension initialization failed.
>   +--- --- ---+ Stack Trace:
>   +--- --- ---+ bingo_server.business.login.service.serviceImpl.VipServiceImpl.getVip(VipServiceImpl.java:21)
>   bingo_server.extension.BingoExtension.init(BingoExtension.java:38)
>   com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSExtensionManager.createExtension(SFSExtensionManager.java:303)
>   com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSZoneManager.createZone(SFSZoneManager.java:425) com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSZoneManager.initializeZones(SFSZoneManager.java:239)
>   com.smartfoxserver.v2.SmartFoxServer.start(SmartFoxServer.java:292)
>   com.smartfoxserver.v2.Main.main(Main.java:27)

It seems the spring annotations did't work.So there is nullpoint exception because there is not object to be injected.

OK,this is my applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- package-scan -->
<context:component-scan base-package="bingo_server">
</context:component-scan>


<!-- data-source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/bingo"></property>
    <property name="user" value="postgres"></property>
    <property name="password" value="123"></property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="15"></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"></property>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="100"></property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="200"></property>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="2000"></property>
</bean>

<!-- SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
            </prop>         

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>bingo_server.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- transaction -->
<bean id="txManage" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>



<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManage">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"></tx:method>     

        <tx:method name="insert*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>

        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="modify*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="change*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>

        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="remove*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="del*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="NOT_SUPPORTED" read-only="true" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="load*" propagation="NOT_SUPPORTED" read-only="true" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="query*" propagation="NOT_SUPPORTED" read-only="true" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"></tx:method>
        <tx:method name="select*" propagation="NOT_SUPPORTED" read-only="true" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"></tx:method>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods" expression="execution(* bingo_server.business.*.service.serviceImpl.*.*(..))"></aop:pointcut>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods"></aop:advisor>
</aop:config>

<!-- aop -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

I‘ve successfully used junit to test my codes, so I think it is because the smartfoxserver. But I can't find how to fix it.

Comment: Is the forward slash necessary?

Comment: Usual Spring `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
   "applicationContext.xml");`

Comment: show us the applicationCotext.xml

Comment: hi Scary Wombat, so where can I put my ApplicationContext.xml file?

Comment: It still has the same problem after I change it to new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "applicationContext.xml");